# Get JSON object from HTML5 data-* attribute with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

Here's my HTML:

```
<input type="text" data-setup='{ "method" : "checkbox" }'>
```

Here's my JavaScript so far:

```
var a = document.querySelectorAll('[data-setup]')
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    alert(a[i].getAttribute('data-setup'));
}
```

This then alerts:

```
ALERT: { "method" : "checkbox" }
```

But how can I access the JSON "method"? I want to essentially be able to alert the word "checkbox". Any help appreciated.

Comment: data-passwrd or data-setup?

Comment: setup, sorry markup glitch. Refresh!

Comment: If you're using jQuery, you can just say
`var a = $('#mySelector').data('setup');`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) would be the simplest way to create a proper object from that JSON:

```
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(a[i].getAttribute('data-psswrd'));
    alert(obj.method); //will alert what was in the method property
    console.log(obj); // should log a proper object
}
```

Of course this won't work in older browsers, so you'll need to shim it if you want that kind of browser support.  Douglas Crockford has a shim [here](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js), and or course jQuery has a [JSON parsing method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) if you were already using that utility.

Comment: Do you know what browsers this would work in? IE8 by any chance? :)

Comment: @Halcyon21 - had to look it up - yeah - looks like this is something IE8 actually *does* support http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/09/10/native-json-in-ie8.aspx

Comment: That's interesting, was more a hopeful question rather than expecting a 'yes' - but that's really good. IE8 has some blessings at least... Thanks for the help, will mark this as chosen.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method for this:

```
var myJSON = JSON.parse( a[i].getAttribute('data-psswrd') );
alert( myJSON );
```

This is supported in all modern browsers and in IE8+.

If you need to support older browsers [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) is little hack. See *Browser compatibility* section.

Comment: yes, now you can use it like Object: `alert( myJSON.method );` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object